# Problem with Sqlite Query - How to convert the code from SQLite v0.9.0 to v1.0.0

Tags: sqlite, julia

I am prettry new to Julia and I am just playing around, and suddenly
the following code starts throwing errors, but it has worked in the past.

```
using SQLite
db = SQLite.DB("db")
data = SQLite.Query(db,"SELECT * FROM d")
```

throws:

> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching
> SQLite.Query(::SQLite.DB, ::String)

can someone please enlighten me wha the problem is? Thank you.

I also tried with lower case: query.

Comment: What are the versions of your Julia and SQLite.jl?

Comment: Well i am using the latest versions of both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short MWE of differences using SQLLite (v0.9.0 vs v1.0.0) with the current Julia version (1.3.1).

You do not have the table so you need to create it first:

```
using SQLite
using DataFrames
db = SQLite.DB("db")
# v0.9.0
SQLite.Query(db,"CREATE TABLE d (col1 INT, col2 varchar2(100))")
# v1.0.0
DBInterface.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE d (col1 INT, col2 varchar2(100))")
```

Now you can check if the table exits:

```
julia> SQLite.tables(db) |> DataFrame
1×1 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ name    │
│     │ String⍰ │
├─────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ d       │
```

Let's insert some rows (note how one should sepearate data from SQL code via precompiled statements):

```
stmt = SQLite.Stmt(db, "INSERT INTO d (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)")
#v0.9.0
SQLite.execute!(stmt; values=(1, "Hello world"))
SQLite.execute!(stmt; values=(2, "Goodbye world"))
#v1.0.0
DBInterface.execute(stmt, (1, "Hello world"))
DBInterface.execute(stmt, (2, "Goodbye world"))
```

Now let us get the data

#### v0.9.0

```
julia> data = SQLite.Query(db,"SELECT * FROM d") |> DataFrame
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ col1   │ col2          │
│     │ Int64⍰ │ String⍰       │
├─────┼────────┼───────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ Hello world   │
│ 2   │ 2      │ Goodbye world │
```

#### v1.0.0

```
julia> data = DBInterface.execute(db, "select * from d") |> DataFrame
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ col1   │ col2          │
│     │ Int64⍰ │ String⍰       │
├─────┼────────┼───────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ Hello world   │
│ 2   │ 2      │ Goodbye world │
```

Comment: Hey! thank you very much for you responce, Well this is great answer but i am sorry I forgot to mention that i alredy have a table called d with daily stock data and w for weekly data, and when i ran SQLite.tables(db) i got in return (name = ["d", "w"],),, and i still get the error and i am using the excat same version of julia

Comment: I extended the answer. Also please try to replicate my example and see if it works (it definitely should).

Comment: # 2 methods for type constructor:
[1] SQLite.Query(stmt::SQLite.Stmt, status::Base.RefValue{Int32}, names::Array{Symbol,1}, types::Array{Type,1}, lookup::Dict{Symbol,Int64}) in SQL

Comment: [2] SQLite.Query(stmt, status, names, types, lookup) in SQLite at C:\Users\shameless\.julia\packages\SQLite\6uY89\src\tables.jl:6

Comment: so  I am missing the right method well thank you very much for pointing this out! hut i alredy tried Pkg.rm and Pkg.add

Comment: OK. edited the post with instructions on what to do.

Comment: Well this is so wiered at this point i have done all above yes even deleted .julia and same 2 methods found afer fresh install then i changed the path and it downloaded all fresh agian and same two methods something is wrong :O

Comment: well i am on windows 10 and this has worked for me before the exact same code and the last test was done with only the SQLite Pkg installed

Comment: I just tried  the following with the same result: julia> Pkg.add(Pkg.PackageSpec(url = "https://github.com/JuliaDatabases/SQLite.jl.git"))

Comment: Mate can you please check if your table.jl line 6 matching the one at github: https://github.com/JuliaDatabases/SQLite.jl/blob/master/src/tables.jl

Comment: Thank you so much ! ty for your time